# Normal distribution in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, random, plsql, normal-distribution

I would like to generate a normal distribution in PL/SQL - Oracle. I know that we can generate this kind of distribution via dbms_random but I would like to specify the paremeters of the normal function (interval, mean, standard deviation).

Is there an easy way to generate this distribution or should I code my own function?

Thanks

Comment: `dbms_random.normal`, documented at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_random.htm#i997841.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to generate numbers from an arbitrary normal distribution, there are only two parameters that make sense, the mean and the standard deviation.  I'm not sure what "interval" you'd want to specify unless you want to produce a truncated distribution.

Given a number from a standard normal distribution (mean 0, standard deviation 1 which is what `dbms_random.normal` returns), it's pretty trivial to convert it to an arbitrary normal distribution.  Just multiply by the standard deviation you want and add the mean that you want.  If you want to then make the distribution non-normal by truncating particularly high or low values, you can do that as well.

Comment: Indeed, The goal was to produce a truncated distribution. Thanks for your help, it saved me a lot of time,

Comment: Note that there are two ways to truncate, which yield quite different results.  One is to put any value beyond the truncation limit at that limit, resulting in a spike for that value.  The other way is to keep retrying until you get something within the limit, which distributes the mass of the truncated portion across throughout the within-limits portion.